# Accessing Contact data of Sync Data Extensions in Journey Builder

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, journeybuilder, marketingcloudapi, contactdata

I would like to use the Contact.WebCart data from the Marketing Cloud Connect sync Data Extension in an Update Contact Activity in Journey Builder.

I'm trying this but not having any luck.

```
{{Contact.Attribute."[Attribute set as found in the Attribute Group]".WebCart_Salesforce_1.Id}}
```

Where WebCart is related a few times via Contact Sync Data Extension, then User Sync Data Extension.

I've tried quiet a few other options with combinations of the Attribute Set, and Data Extension.
For instance, this works:

```
{{Contact.Attribute.Contact_Salesforce_1.Id}}
```

But these don't work:

```
{{Contact.Attribute.Account_Salesforce_1.Id}}
{{Contact.Attribute.Contact_Salesforce_1.Account_Salesforce_1.Id}}
```

Has anyone had success before?

Answer (score 0):

1.) In your Journey add a Object Activity and select the contact object 2.)Select a field that is free form text, not like a picklist 3.)In the Attributes select Journey Data > Entry:Trigger 4.)Select your value that is present in the data extension that feeds your journey.  You'll need to add it via your automation/query pulling from the contact object. 5.) Copy the handlebar code.

[image]